# How to model "current month" so conditional formats ignore future months in PowerBI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am generating a matrix/table showing monthly actuals compared to two financial forecasts.  I need to conditionally format the backround color in scenarios where the ACTUALS are off by +/- 100.  I have a few dimension tables and 3 fact tables.

[image: relationship diagram]

Within my FactActuals table, I created a simple measure to calculate the difference between the actuals and forecast1:

```
DiffToFC1 = SUM(FactForecast1[Amount])-sum(FactActuals[Amount])
```

The conditional background rules are:
[image: conditional background rules]

This works except the formatting pushes out into the future for months that have not occurred... for which I would never have actuals. My "current month" is a single constant that I can retrieve from my data but I am uncertain how and where to model that value so conditional formatting can be applied correctly.  It is not "Today()"... it can be pulled or inferred from my source data but I don't know how to expose it.

[image]

Question

**How to model "current month" and reference it in conditional background calculations for matrix visualization values so future months are ignored?**  Null/Blank values in past should be considered zero for the purpose of styling... while null/bank values in future are ignored.

[Link to sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VRJI7Z7SVr2X11C1VTEn2n3g2hGIevK4/view?usp=sharing)

I updated the measure to exclude blanks using the following:

```
DiffToFC1-ISBLANK = IF(NOT(ISBLANK(sum(FactActuals[Amount]))), SUM(FactForecast1[Amount])-sum(FactActuals[Amount]))
```

[image]

This prevents null values from showing in future but does not allow historical months to be treated as zero for the purposes of conditional formatting.  In the linked sample file, April 2022 is a historical month that has no actuals but should be highlighted.

[image: isblank correctly ignores future months]
[image: isblank does not handle historical blank values]

Comment: Please can you split your question into separate questions as there are too many to answer in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your formatting, try changing your measure to this

```
DiffToFC1 = 

VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Year]) & SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[MonthNumber])
VAR t = YEAR(TODAY()) & MONTH(TODAY()) 

RETURN 
IF(d<=t, SUM(FactForecast1[Amount])-sum(FactActuals[Amount])+0)
```

Comment: That works to prevent future months from rendering but fails the scenario where historical months should be treated as 0 when blank.  In the sample file, filter for year=2002 and see that April is blank and should be considered zero.... I will update the original post with this example.

Comment: That looks like it will work but my "current month" is a value from my data not TODAY()... i.e., it's the last financial month closed.  Would it be as simple as modeling a single table with a single column containing the "current month" and using that in the measure?  That seems to make sense but being new to PBI I'm uncertain if that's an effective design.

Comment: Yes, just set your stop month to wherever it is stored if not using today, You can simplify things if you flesh out your date table with more columns too.

Comment: in what way would fleshing out the date table simplify things?  do you have something in mind that would be beneficial in this scenario?

Comment: Normally the date table has a column that stores year month as 202302 and that would simplify things a little bit.